# Live time in prompt - bash

Tags: bash, prompt, time

Is there any way to have the live time in the promt, such that when I execute a command, the time shown is the time the command was executed?

So far I'm using `S1="[\t me@here]\$ "` for example, and this is the prompt:
`[04:30:39 me@here]$`

If I run a few commands, I get this:

```
[04:30:39 me@here]$ date #command1
Tue Dec  3 04:30:47 EET 2019 #result1
[04:30:47 me@here]$ date #command2
Tue Dec  3 04:31:01 EET 2019 #result2
[04:31:01 me@here]$ date #command4
Tue Dec  3 04:31:04 EET 2019 #result4
```

As you can see, the time of command1's execution is on the prompt of command2.

I would like a timer that "ticks" with the prompt on idle, if it's possible.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/360063/how-to-show-a-running-clock-in-terminal-before-the-command-prompt

Comment: Suggestion: `tmux` shows a clock in the bottom right by default

Answer (score 0):

this will do that:

https://github.com/christopher-barry/bash-color-tools

run install, then run setup-prompt for each user. The prompt is theme-able, so you can set colors, have different stuff displayed, etc.